# How can I round seconds to 0 with dayJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dayjs

I am creating an app which asks the users for 2 dates, then it calculates the time between them dates.

But the dates have seconds in them so instead of 90 minutes I am getting 89 minutes.

So I can convert this:

startTime: Sat Apr 09 2022 09:00:39 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)

Into this:

startTime: Sat Apr 09 2022 09:00:**00** GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)

I would preferably do this with DayJS

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call [`setUTCSeconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCSeconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution with the help of James!

```
values.startTime = dayjs(time[0].setUTCSeconds(0)).toDate();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateVal = dayjs(new Date());
dateVal = dateVal.set('seconds', 0).set('millisecond', 0);
```

https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/set

https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/get#list-of-all-available-units